# Python скролл страницы с помощью pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

В документации к модулю pyautogui указана команда pyautogui.scroll(10) но это не работает. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окно, к которому применяется scroll, должно быть активно (например, с помощью функции `pyautogui.click()`). И скроллирование страницы вниз - `pyautogui.scroll(-10)`.